# If $p$ is a prime number, prove that for any $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $p |a^p+(p-1)!a$ and $p|(p-1)!a^p+a$

Tags: number-theory

If $p$ is a prime number, prove that for any $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $$p |a^p+(p-1)!a$$ and $$p|(p-1)!a^p+a$$ I totally got no idea how to start. Can anyone give some hints?

Comment: Hints: Wilson's theorem, Fermat's theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the first one.

We want to show that $a^p + (p-1)!a \equiv 0 \pmod p$. From Fermat's Little Theorem, we know that $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$. By Wilson's Theorem, $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$.

Together, these mean that $a^p + (p-1)!a \equiv a + -a \equiv 0 \pmod p$, which is what we wanted to show.

Use Wilson's Theorem and Fermat's Little Theorem to prove the second one too.